# When will the 64-bit version of JDIC be available?

Tags: java, jdic

My Java program needs lots of memory to run, the 32-bit version of Java max out at 1.5 GB, my system has 4 GB of RAM, so I decided to run it under the 64-bit version of Java, and yet the JDIC won't work, which affects my program, so I wonder if anyone knows when the 64-bit JDIC will be available ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running a 64-bit OS and a 64-bit JVM, you could try the latest version of Java 6u13 as I believe there is improve client side support for 64-bit applications.

Note: I wouldn't suggest you use more than 1/2 to 2/3 of your memory for Java's heap.  You may also need more main memory to see a real improvement in the amount of memory you can really use.
(As you need to leave memory for the OS, other programs and Java's own shared memory/libraries etc)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I am not sure if you've answered my question, I tried to run 64-bit of Java, but since my project uses JDIC, it won't work properly without the 64-bit support of JDIC, does Java 6u13 offer 64-bit version support of JDIC ? I need it to simulate desktop browser.

Comment: I believe Java 6u12 added support for 64-bit applets and browsers.  I don't know about JDIC, but I believe it is worth a try.  I was trying to point out you will probably have more issues increasing the maximum memory if you only have 4 GB.

Comment: Another option may be to run a 32-bit service which is a bridge between you 64-bit application and JDIC.  It could communicate via sockets or RMI. (Ugly, but it would work)

Comment: Good advice, I've done some research and found JDIC was sort of taken over by JWebPane which can function as a browser panel, and it is supposed to be part of next version of the main Java package, I'm looking forward to it. As to RAM, once I move over to 64-bit, my available RAM to Java will likely increase from 1.5G to 3G, that will last a good while before I need to get a new PC, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I only used Desktop (org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.Desktop) from JDIC and now I can use java.awt.Desktop from Java 6. There's a few differences but essentially they both have the same functionality.