# Is 64bit jdic libraries available for solaris?

Tags: jdic

Does anyone know if there is a way to make jdic work in solaris (64bit version)??

I could only manage to find 32bit jdic libraries :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it contain native code?  Have you tried compiling it from source?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/845858/889576) answer may be usefull for you...

Comment: And if you can't build a jdic from source for Solaris x64, obviously, the answer will be NO. More to say: I didn't find any issues at jdic JIRA bugtracker, mentioned Solaris x64.

Answer (score 0):

The project seems dead.

Plus http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/index.html has most of its page 404...

Someone tried to make a 64 bits library (not tested): http://jimmi1977.blogspot.fr/2010/02/64-bit-version-of-jdic.html

- http://www.java.net/node/648811
- [When will the 64-bit version of JDIC be available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845570/when-will-the-64-bit-version-of-jdic-be-available)

I think you should look for an alternative (like Desktop).